# jboss as 7 module dependency browser tool

Tags: jboss, dependencies

Does anybody know of a tool, which supports browsing the jboss as 7 module dependency graph ?

best regards
Hardy Henneberg

Answer (score 2):

jboss-modules have that built in.

go to JBOSS_HOME and do

```
java -jar jboss-modules.jar -mp modules -deptree <name-of-the-module-you-are-interested-in>
```